# meaning of Solr query

Tags: java, spring, solr

I am a newbie to solr and i am trying to understand the different way of querying.
I saw a code example as below:

```
'some search text'::type:value1:type:value2
```

Can anybody help me understand what the above string does?

I know if it is only `type:value1` searches the field **type** with the value **value1**

Another question as how can I search a value in multiple fields? basically I want to do **OR** on fields.

Eg:`type:value1 OR name:value1`

Any link to the beginners tutorial or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of solr are you using, please? The query support has changed between e.g. solr 4 and solr 5.

For your second query, if you are e.g. using solr 5 and you are browsing the appropriate core from the browse URL then you should be able to type in `type:blue OR name:blue` and you'll get the expected results. However, more likely you'll want to watch your case-sensitivity here, and you want e.g. `type:blue OR name:Blue` This will get rendered as `/solr/core/browse?q=type%3Ablue+OR+name%3Blue`etc.